# Postal order has my name mis-spelt, can I still cash it?

Tags: united-kingdom, postal-order

I've received a postal order, but the last letter of my surname is missing on it, can I still cash it?

Comment: Elsey Did it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll only know if you try. I suspect if you play it cool, it won't matter. If they point it out, just say "Oh, look at that! They must have mistyped it".

Answer (score 2):

I've never had an issue with this sort of thing. Depending on your bank you can probably just deposit it in an ATM. I've never heard of a computer that even tries to read the "pay to:" section, let alone one that could figure it out if it was wrong.